# Upgrade to WP8 "No XAML was found at the location '/LaunchPage.xaml'."

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, manifest

I have upgraded a Windows Phone 7 app to Windows Phone 8 and now it won't run. It throws a `RootFrame_NavigationFailed` with message `No XAML was found at the location '/LaunchPage.xaml'`.

I have changed nothing from my app, which has been working for over a year now, other than run the WP8 upgrade. What could be the issue?

Maybe related - If I try to do anything in the WMAppManifest.xml designer, for example checking "Support for large Tiles", it says "Unable to Load Manifest" "The document contains errors that must be fixed before the designer can be loaded. Reload the designer after the errors have been fixed." Looking at the xml, nothing seems out of place. May or may not be related to this issue but thought I'd add this.

Comment: Try Clear Solution action and then Rebuild it

Comment: No, that was obviously one of the first things I would try. Isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the best solution but I got it working by creating a new WP8 project and importing all the source files in. If anyone else has a better solution I'd be very willing to hear it, and will mark the full, proper, correct answer as required.

Answer (score 5):

Had similar issue after WP7 to WP8 upgrade. I fixed it by opening AssemblyInfo.cs and changing

```
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite)]
```

to

```
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute("en-US")]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
But I fix it by following the next steps.

1. Open YouProject > Properties > WMAppManifest.xml
2. Look if the Navigation Page is correct

Save, close and run again.

I hope this help you.

Comment: I had the Navigation Page correct. It just seems that the actual upgrade from WP7 to 8 doesn't work right.